# Closing a window in Mission Control

Tags: window-manager, mission-control

Is it possible to close a window within the Mission Control interface?

E.g. by highlighting a window and perform a keyboard/mouse shortcut?

Answer (score 3):

If you use [Better Touch Tool](http://www.boastr.de/), you can configure a shortcut for the keyboard, mouse, magic mouse, trackpad or even Apple remote to close a window, and it will work in Exposé.

BTT is free and it works really well, in my case I configured the close shortcut as a pinch out gesture for my trackpad.

Comment: This works. 2 things to note, however. Instead of choosing the Cmd-W shortcut, you must explicitly choose the action that closes the window and says that it works in Expose. The second thing to note, is that although it does close the window, it still maintains a spot for the app inside of mission control until you exit out of mission control. This is more of a cosmetic rather than functional issue though. The first problem is more of an issue though, since I prefer to have the command bound to Cmd-W so that it can close a tab in Chrome, for example.

Comment: About your first point: yes, indeed, but you could disable the global shortcut I guess and reassign it to the "special close that works in expose" inside BTT, moreover you can define "per app" shortcut in BTT to reset it for Chrome. For the second point, I noticed that effect also, that's not perfect.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Mission Control Plus](https://fadel.io/MissionControlPlus) to close windows in Mission Control: it adds an "X" sign on the upper left corner of a window when you hover over it; clicking the "X" sign would close that window.

You can also close windows by using the cmd+W keyboard shortcut, or the mouse middle click.

Full disclosure: I'm the developer behind Mission Control Plus.